# «Страшно» — сказуемое или вводное слово?

Tags: синтаксис, вводные-слова, сказуемые, части-речи, предикатив

*...показывает зубы, и страшно, вдруг сорвётся.*
Подскажите, "страшно" здесь выступает в роли сказуемого в безличном предложении? Или вообще в роли вводного слова?
Склоняюсь к первому варианту, так как это предикатив, но в контексте что-то смущает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предложение, конечно же, лучше давать целиком, а то приходится додумывать: то ли рыба зубастая на крючке, то ли чудовище цепи.
*Страшно* — это не вводное слово, а сказуемое, выраженное категорией состояния (нулевая безличная связка; *тихо, ветрено, жарко*).
А смущение возникает из-за отсутствия правильного знака (я бы поставила тире).

*Интересно, потому что показывает зубы, и страшно — вдруг сорвётся.*

*Он попросил слова с тем дрожанием сердца, какое бывает у неопытного пловца, когда тот бросается с вышки в воду: и хочется нырнуть, и страшно ― вдруг утонешь…* (В. Ф. Панова. Спутники); *И мне было щекотно и страшно ― вдруг и правда откусит!* (М. Шишкин. Письмовник).

[Безличные предложения](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/sintaksis/primeryi-bezlichnyih-predlozheniy.html)
[Страшно](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%BE)