# Чем обусловлена запятая в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, и, члены-предложения, присоединительный

*Огонь был новой важной силой в моей нынешней жизни, и силой спасительной.*

Наткнулась на данное предложение в одной из практических работ по русскому. Можете подсказать, чем является "и силой спасительной" и как объяснить постановку запятой перед "и"? Единственный вариант, который приходит в голову – это одна из частей ССП. Но в задании подразумевается, что в предложении есть либо однородные члены, либо вводная конструкция, либо одна из поясняющих/уточняющих.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Составители тестов и упражнений часто кромсают и переделывают готовые предложения писателей. Так случилось и здесь.

*Решение «да или нет» было простое. Огонь – на него надо идти не раздумывая. Огонь был новой важной силой в моей нынешней ночи. **Спасительной силой*** (Варлам Шаламов. «Воскрешение лиственницы» [[источник 1]](https://sharlib.com/read_250467-38), [[источник 2]](https://litlife.club/books/122423/read?page=68)).

В данном случае, к счастью, изменение не повлияло на определение синтаксической роли рассматриваемых слов – они являются присоединительной (дополнительной) конструкцией, которая, можно сказать, уточняет или поясняет предыдущие слова.

> 1. Присоединительные члены предложения, которые содержат дополнительные разъяснения или замечания, вводимые в середину либо в конец высказывания, выделяются (или отделяются) **запятыми** (реже используются **тире, точка, многоточие**): <...>
>    *А Рудин заговорил о самолюбии, **и очень дельно заговорил** (Т.);
>
>    Об этом ведутся споры, **и споры горячие**;
>
>    Нужно идти вперёд, **и идти как можно быстрее.***
>    <...>
>    *Пойду-ка посижу у себя. **Оденусь** (Н. И.);
>
>    Смотрю, в одиннадцатой роте сигналы учат. **Хором** (Купр.);
>
>    У Елены беда тут стряслась. **Большая*** (Панф.).

Источник: [Присоединительные конструкции](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=120) (справочник Розенталя).

Comment: Самое-то интересное, что присоединительная конструкция в задании не подразумевалась (если верить автору вопроса).

Comment: Порылась. Нашла. (http://philology.bsu.by/documents/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%20%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B9%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B/%D0%94%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%86%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%8B/%D0%A1%D0%9E%D0%92%D0%A0%D0%95%D0%9C%D0%95%D0%9D%D0%9D%D0%AB%D0%99%20%D0%A0%D0%A3%D0%A1%D0%A1%D0%9A%D0%98%D0%99%20%D0%AF%D0%97%D0%AB%D0%9A/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%20%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%208.pdf) Ага, все-таки подразумевалась. А то меня чуть сомнения не загрызли.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова , автор вопроса нагло забыл, извините. спасибо за внимательность!

Comment: @Пррр Спасибо за вопрос и оценку!

Comment: @Пррр Мне кажется, Вам нужно отметить и принять ответ на [этот вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/472429/Страшно-сказуемое-или-вводное-слово).

Comment: Саша, радетель ты мой...